# Adding Enumeration Value to Silverlight Attribute/Property

Tags: wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties, attached-properties

In the `<ImageBrush/>` element, there are `AlignmentX` and `AlignmentY` attributes with values Left/Center/Right and Top/Center/Bottom, respectively.

What I'm wanting to do is set my own value in, for example, `AlignmentX` either as a value or as another enumeration like `AlignmentX="HalfCenter"` where `HalfLeft` equals my own value (halfway between Center and Left). For example, if I have this:

```
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="0" Stroke="LimeGreen" StrokeThickness="16" Canvas.Top="0" 
               Width="400" Height="400" >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="newone.jpg" 
                       Stretch="None" AlignmentX="HalfLeft" AlignmentY="Top"  />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

I don't know if this is a Dependency Property, Attached Property or otherwise (don't yet know how to create those). In the helpfile, it says in `TileBrush.AlignmentXProperty` field: `Public Shared ReadOnly AlignmentXProperty As DependencyProperty`. Does the *ReadOnly* word here mean that I can't set this property to a custom property?

If this can't be an override of that property, how can I create my own? I think this is an Attached Property and it could be called something different, like `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` that set an `ImageBrush` to a location inside its parent `Shape`. I'm getting very confused by the SL documentation on how I would do this though (almost no examples in VB.NET - but even the C# ones aren't all that revealing).

If it is possible, how would I get started on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself the pain and just use a value convertor and even that is going to be a little tricky, since you are going to have to apply a rendertransform or something to react to your enums.

You also could write your own panel which is probably a better idea.

You have a few different problems here to confront, creating the attached property, validating the enum, having the enum do what you want it to do when it is set.

Your also going to have to learn about MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride

If you just can't help yourself ... [Look Here](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/17/silverlight-design-time-extensibility.aspx)

Comment: Great advice on the `RenderTransform`, hadn't even thought of that. But that gets me exactly what I need.